# Non-linear 1st order differential equation of $~x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=x\sqrt{y}~~~$where$~\sqrt{y}~$exists

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think this is the first time when I handle of **non-linear** differential equation.

$$  \underbrace{x \frac{dy}{dx}  + y = x\sqrt{ y } }_{x > 0}   \tag{1}   $$

$$  \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{1}{ x } y = \sqrt{ y }  $$

$$   \underbrace{\frac{d}{dx}\left(yx\right)}_{\text{LHS of eqn1} }  = x \sqrt{ y } ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{What can I do for next?}   $$

Which website is suitable for this problem?

**ADD**

I got the following after I have read the post of @Gerd

$$  \frac{d}{dx}\left(yx\right) = x \sqrt{ y } 　　\tag{2}  $$

$$  \frac{d}{dx}\left(xy\right) = x^{\frac{1}{2} } \cdot x^{\frac{1}{2} } \sqrt{ y }  $$

$$ = \sqrt{ x } \sqrt{ xy }  $$

$$  z:=xy \tag{3}  $$

$$  \frac{  dz  }{ dx   } = \sqrt{ x }  \sqrt{ z } \tag{4}  $$

$$  \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ z }   } \frac{dz}{dx} = \sqrt{ x }  $$

$$  \int_{ }^{ } \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ z }  } \frac{dz}{dx}  \,dx   = \int_{ }^{ } \sqrt{ x }  \,dx    $$

$$  \int_{ }^{ } \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ z }  }  \,dz = \int_{ }^{ } x^{\frac{1}{ 2 } } \,dx     $$

$$  \int_{ }^{ } \frac{  1  }{  z^{\frac{1}{2} }  }  \,dz   = \frac{  x^{\frac{  3  }{   2 } }  }{  \frac{  3  }{  2  }   } + \text{const}_{1} $$

$$  \int_{ }^{ } z^{-1/2} \,dz = \frac{  2  }{  3  } x\sqrt{ x }  + \text{const}_{1}  $$

$$  \frac{  z^{\frac{1}{2}}  }{  \frac{1}{2}   }  = \frac{  2  }{  3  } x\sqrt{ x }  + \text{const}_{1}  $$

$$   2z^{\frac{1}{2}}  = \frac{  2  }{  3  } x\sqrt{ x }  + \text{const}_{1}  $$

$$  2 \sqrt{ z } = \frac{  2  }{  3  } x\sqrt{ x } + \text{const}_{1}  $$

$$  2 \sqrt{ yx } = \frac{  2  }{  3  } x\sqrt{ x } + \text{const}_{1}  $$

$$  2 \sqrt{ yx } - \frac{  2  }{  3  } x\sqrt{ x } = \text{const}_{1}  $$

$$  \underbrace{\sqrt{ x }  \left( 2 \sqrt{ y } - \frac{  2  }{  3  } x  \right) = \text{const}_{1} }_{\text{general solution} } ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{Is this also correct?}   $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of a [Bernoulli differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation), wich has a well know method of solution by transforming in a linear equation.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if you are interested in solutions on intervals $I\subseteq (0, \infty)$ write

$$
\frac{d}{dx}(xy(x)) =x \sqrt{y(x)} = \sqrt{x}\sqrt{xy(x)}.
$$

Then substitute $z(x):=xy(x)$ and solve $z'(x)=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{z(x)}$ by separation of variables (initial values $>0$ are adequate here). Then $y(x)=z(x)/x$ is a solution of the original problem.

Comment: I added the stuff to my post.

Comment: Calculations seem correct to me. Now you can resolve to $y$. However, I would not call it the general solution. If you want to solve the ode in $(-\infty,0)$ you have to set $x=\sqrt{-x}\sqrt{-x}$. Moreover $y(x)=0$ is a solution on any interval.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'+\frac{y}{x} = \sqrt{y}$$

$$\frac{y'}{\sqrt{y}} +\frac{\sqrt{y}}{x} = 1$$

Using
$$z=\sqrt{y}$$

$$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\cdot y'$$

$$2\cdot\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{y'}{\sqrt{y}}$$

Replace

$$2\cdot\frac{dz}{dx} +\frac{z}{x} = 1$$

And now you have built a linear system